# Magento Downloadable products download after Invoicing

Tags: php, magento

There is a big trouble for me.

I have set a condition from Admin setting i.e. the Downloadable product should be download after creating the Invoice of an Order.

Please help for the below conditions -

> - Where I need to change if I want to download product of an order which contains Grand total 0.00 without changing my Admin Setting.

Without creating Invoice of an Order my customers should be able to download the Product.

Comment: same issue here ... did u find any solution ?

Comment: No WonderLand. I am still trying to find a feasible way.

Comment: ok I have wrote an extension today ... we will probably release it for free ... I will let u know

Answer (score 0):

I found this a good question and I've been looking for a solution myself.

I didn't find a direct solution, though maybe a work-around:

I suggest creating a transactional e-mail for that type of event.

Create an e-mail template under "new order" where the product price = 0.00.

Include the download link in the e-mail template and your customer doesn't have to wait for ur invoice.